# EntityFrameWork CodeFirst - Error when Migrating

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I am new to `MVC ASP.NET` and I am currently taking some lectures. But anyway I am trying to migrate to DB using `Entity Framework`

First my code:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
```

Problem is with this line `public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }` as when I remove it the migration works fine.

My Customer Class(just couple of properties):

```
public class Customer : Controller
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int HouseNum { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
        public string Town { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
    }
```

Error I receive when running command `add-migration InitalModel`:

```
System.NotSupportedException: The type 'System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection+IgnoreRouteInternal' and the type 'System.Web.Mvc.RouteCollectionExtensions+IgnoreRouteInternal' both have the same simple name of 'IgnoreRouteInternal' and so cannot be used in the same model. All types in a given model must have unique simple names. Use 'NotMappedAttribute' or call Ignore in the Code First fluent API to explicitly exclude a property or type from the model.
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.GetExistingEdmType[T](EdmModel model, Type type)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.MapEntityType(Type type)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.MapDerivedTypes(Type type, EntityType entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.MapEntityType(Type type)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.MapDerivedTypes(Type type, EntityType entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.MapEntityType(Type type)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.NavigationPropertyMapper.Map(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, EntityType entityType, Func`1 entityTypeConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.MapEntityType(Type type)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.NavigationPropertyMapper.Map(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, EntityType entityType, Func`1 entityTypeConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.MapEntityType(Type type)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.NavigationPropertyMapper.Map(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, EntityType entityType, Func`1 entityTypeConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.MapEntityType(Type type)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.NavigationPropertyMapper.Map(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, EntityType entityType, Func`1 entityTypeConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.MapEntityType(Type type)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.MapDerivedTypes(Type type, EntityType entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.MapEntityType(Type type)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.NavigationPropertyMapper.Map(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, EntityType entityType, Func`1 entityTypeConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.MapEntityType(Type type)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.NavigationPropertyMapper.Map(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, EntityType entityType, Func`1 entityTypeConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mappers.TypeMapper.MapEntityType(Type type)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.MapTypes(EdmModel model)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ModelBeingInitialized()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(DbContext context, XmlWriter writer)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetModel>b__0(XmlWriter w)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(Action`1 writeXml)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(DbContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration, DbContext usersContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState, Boolean calledByCreateDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration migrationsConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Scaffold(String migrationName, String language, String rootNamespace, Boolean ignoreChanges)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.Execute(String name, Boolean force, Boolean ignoreChanges)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
The type 'System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection+IgnoreRouteInternal' and the type 'System.Web.Mvc.RouteCollectionExtensions+IgnoreRouteInternal' both have the same simple name of 'IgnoreRouteInternal' and so cannot be used in the same model. All types in a given model must have unique simple names. Use 'NotMappedAttribute' or call Ignore in the Code First fluent API to explicitly exclude a property or type from the model.
```

I checked other posts and people suggest to check names in models. I've done that and there are no repeating names...

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks
aberforth

Answer (score 1):

The issue looks to be because your Customer class is inheriting from Controller. Can you remove that and try again

Comment: Worked like a charm!!! it's weird though because I copied the code from the course I'm taking on Udemy and it worked for the instructor...
Anyway, thank You!